# How to add multiple button and label in each row on UITableview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm a newbie. I want to create a UITableview which has 2 button and 3 label in each row. And i want to when load tableview, it'll check state of each button, then set image for them. After user click on other button in another tabbar, uitableview will be reloaded and set image as stats of  them. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

I tried below code but image of marketButton is overlap but Price label works fine, not overlap:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        UILabel *pricelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 0, 80, 30)];
        pricelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        pricelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        pricelabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        pricelabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        pricelabel.tag = 3000;
        //pricelabel.hidden = YES;

        pricelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: pricelabel];
        [pricelabel release];

    }

    UIButton *marketButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    if([sellingArray count]>0)
    {
    NSLog(@"sellingArray %@",sellingArray);
    if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) // nothing
    {

        [marketButton setSelected:NO];
        [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        marketButton.enabled = YES;

    }
    else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"])  // marketplace
    {
        [marketButton setSelected:YES];
        [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        marketButton.enabled = YES;

    }
    }

    if([priceNewArray count]> 0)
    {
        UILabel *pricelbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3000];
        pricelbl.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[priceNewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        if ([sellingArray count]>0) {
            if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"]){

                pricelbl.hidden = NO;
            }
            else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
                pricelbl.hidden = YES;

            }

        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What have done so far? Have tried anything or you are asking us to build this project for you?

Comment: @XCodeMonkey: i updated my code that tried. Please see it. thanks much

Comment: The image you are trying to set overlaps what? The button itself or two images overlapping each other?

Comment: @XCodeMonkey: This tableview created in tabbar1 ,when i click on another tabbar then go back tabbar1, i called function [Tableview reloadata], i see image of button is not clear before set new image for it.When first load, it set "image1", then click on this tabbar again, it set "image1" on upper recent "image1", and it is overlap.

Comment: Then in that case clear the image before reloading the tableview. Then after reloading the new image needs to be checked so it can take the place of the old one.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey: so how can checking it before set image? I need check it in "cellForRowAtIndexPath"function ?

Comment: Check the answer below. That should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt see the code for adding `marketButton` in the cell.

Basically, when `tableView reloadData` is called, it will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and since you are using `reusableidentifier`, it will return a reused cell which already have the label and button. So if you are creating the button instance again, then it will overlap.

Anyways, the basic idea to do this is, create the labels and buttons inside `cell==nil` block as you have created like now and assign a tag to them. Outside the `cell==nil` block, get the control from the cell using tag and update the control as you wish.

So the logical flow of code will be like this

```
if (nil == cell) {

    //Create new cell instance with reusable identifier
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //Create the controls and assign tag
    UILabel *pricelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 0, 80, 30)];
    pricelabel.tag = 3000;
    [cell.contentView addSubview: pricelabel];
    [pricelabel release];

    UIButton *marketButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressed:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [marketButton setTag:3001];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: marketButton ];
}
//In the block outside, you can get the controls from the cell and update it.
UILabel *priceLbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3000];
UIButton*marketBtn = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3001];

//Add the code for updating the button based on some status.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: + 1 for beating me to it by seconds.:)

Comment: But when [Selling count] < 3001 , it crashed @HRM

Comment: It show error : -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3001 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'

Comment: Please see my new problem at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394721/how-to-get-index-of-uibutton-that-viewwithtag-in-uitableview-ios thanks much