# How to get index of UIButton that viewwithtag in uitableview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem: I want to get index of UIButton in tableview. I created uitableview has 2 uibutton in each row, but when i click on uibutton, it get index incorrect. 
Code create UITableview :

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"AllItemsArrayarray: %@", temp);
    return [temp count];
}
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` function

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UIButton *market = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [market setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 30, 30)];
        [market setTag:4000];
        [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:market];
    }

    UIButton *marketButton = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4000];
  if([sellingArray count]>0)
{
    NSLog(@"sellingArray %@",sellingArray);
    if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) // nothing
    {

        [marketButton setSelected:NO];
        [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        marketButton.enabled = YES;

    }
    else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"])  // marketplace
    {
        [marketButton setSelected:YES];
        [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        marketButton.enabled = YES;

    }
}

    return cell;
}
```

And `marketPressedAction` function

```
- (void)marketPressedAction:(id)sender
{
    buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
    buttontag = buttonPressed.tag ;
    NSLog(@"Market button click at row %d",buttontag);
}
```

When table has 5 row, I click on button, it shows error:

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4000 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
```

Comment: Show code of didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: So your trying to access an array based on the button tag, which with an array of 5 elements, and object at index 4000 is obviously out of bounds. Which is what is causing the error.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you'r trying to accomplish with this code. What is the point of marketButton? Why are you alloc that?

Comment: What where are you trying to access an array? (cause of error)

Comment: Your code seems fine to me though I could not understand why you've used marketButton. Show more code. I don't think this code part causing any issue.

Comment: I updated my code , Please see it

Comment: @CRDave: i do not write code of didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: put the breakpoint and tell us where exactly(which line) is causing the error

Comment: @iOSCoder: when run to marketpressAction function , it get index of uibutton and then get data from Array but this array has 5 items, index of uibutton is 4000 . so it broken

Comment: use break point for got where it crushed ?? nd what is sellingArray ??

Comment: not sure whether you're telling the answer or asking the question...

Comment: sellingArray.count is 5,but you are probably trying to access the item at index 4000..does it makes sense?

Comment: yes , correct @iOSCoder. seelingArray has 5 item but uibutton that i clicked on has tag 4000, so my app crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set tag using indexpath.row

```
 UIButton *market ;

       if (nil == cell) 
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
           }

              market = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                [market setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 30, 30)];
                [market setTag:indexPath.row];
                [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
             if([sellingArray count]>0)
       {
    NSLog(@"sellingArray %@",sellingArray);
    if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) // nothing
    {

        [market setSelected:NO];
        [market setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        market.enabled = YES;

    }
    else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"])  // marketplace
    {
        [market setSelected:YES];
        [market setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        market.enabled = YES;

    }
                [cell.contentView addSubview:market];
```

Comment: thanks, i tried but it break in line :if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) // nothing
    {...}

Comment: this is error in console : [UITableViewCellContentView setSelected:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x957e700'

Comment: i changed as your code but when i reloadData to change image of uibutton, it still crash :(

Comment: check my updated answer when cell nil then cell new allocated

Comment: Thanks but if use your code, image of uibutton is overlap, it back previous my issue

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments you put below the question, I think you are trying to access the item in your array based on which button is clicked in table view. First of all, you are setting the tag of your button to 4000, then when you try to access the item from your array at index of the tag of button clicked, obviously it will be out of bounds because you are trying to access the object in the array at index 4000 whereas the array has only 5 items.

To achieve that with your approach, your button should have the tag equal to the index of object that particular cell is representing. So instead of

```
[market setTag:4000];
```

you should do this instead:

```
[market setTag:indexPath.row];
```

Then when you access the tag in your button's selector method, it will be the same as the index of object that cell represented.

Comment: That out of bounds error occurs when you try to fetch an object at index out of the number of items the array is currently holding. So check how are you doing that.

Comment: it breaks in line :if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) // nothing {...}

Comment: The `numberOfRowsInSection:` method is returning [temp count] whereas you are accessing sellingArr in `celForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Thats contrasting. Both arrays must have same count at least for it to work.

Comment: yes, sellingarray has item equals temp array.My problem is when click on button, it always return tag is 4000.