# Multiple rows inside table view cell for tableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, multiple-columns

I have an array of objects that I would like to display information of inside a table view. I am trying to find some good examples on the web on how to display multiple columns per row or at least give the impression of multiple columns.

For example.

Object
Person
-FirstName
-LastName

My array has a collection of multiple person objects.

I want to display the data as such:

John Smith

Jane Doh

Don Johnson

Marco Polo

So far I have this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    Person *Item = [self.Data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.text = Item.FirstName;

    //Add the rest of the properties as separate columns

    return cell;


}
```

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uiexpandabletableview 2)https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sdnestedtable

Comment: @CodeMilian your question is not clear what you want to achieve? can you explain little

Answer (score 1):

For column behavior you can add label on your cell and display the text on label.

```
cell.label1.text = Item.FirstName;
cell.label2.text = Item.LastName;
cell.label3.text = Item.City;
```

Design the cell according to your requirement and provide a frame to label as it looks like column in table view :)

Comment: Thank you Saurav. How exactly do I go about doing that? I see one label. How do I add the others?

Comment: Hi @CodeMilian Please go through the following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393546/how-to-add-multiple-button-and-label-in-each-row-on-uitableview-ios

Comment: Thank you I ended up doing pretty much the same thing.